# how to display orderby descending in LinQ

Tags: c#, linq

I want to display order by descending in `LINQ` with web service, and I have a `LINQ` query that I want to order by the most recently created time.

Here My web Service (GetContent.asmx.cs):

```
[WebMethod]
public string[] GetContentText(string NamaPage, string TanggalAkses, string key)
{
    string[] ret = new string[4] { null, null, null, null };

    if (clsEncrypt.DecodeFrom64(key) == TanggalAkses)
    {

        FrontEndContent dt = db.FrontEndContent.FirstOrDefault(m => m.NamaPage.ToLower() == NamaPage.ToLower().OrderByDescending(m => m.CreatedTime.ToList());
       //List<FrontEndContent> dt = db.FrontEndContent.OrderByDescending(m => new { m.CreatedTime }).ToList();

        if (dt != null)
        {
            ret[0] = dt.Id.ToString();
            ret[1] = dt.HeaderText;
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(ret[1]))
            {
                ret[1] = "";
            }
            ret[2] = dt.SubHeaderText;
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(ret[1]))
            {
                ret[2] = "";
            }
            ret[3] = dt.ContentText;
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(ret[1]))
            {
                ret[3] = "";
            }
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

And my model here:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace penerimaan.Models
{
    public class FrontEndContent
    {
        private ModelEntities db = new ModelEntities();

        [Key]
        [DisplayName("ID")]
        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Nama Page is Required")]
        [DisplayName("Nama Page")]
        [StringLength(110)]
        public string NamaPage { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Header Text")]
        [StringLength(110)]
        public string HeaderText { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Sub Header Text")]
        [StringLength(110)]
        public string SubHeaderText { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Content")]
        [StringLength(10000)]
        [AllowHtml]
        public string ContentText { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Created Time")]
        public System.DateTime? CreatedTime { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Updated Time")]
        public System.DateTime? UpdatedTime { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Created By")]
        public int? CreatedBy_Id { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Updated By")]
        public int? UpdatedBy_Id { get; set; }


        public IEnumerable<FrontEndContent> SelectData()
        {
            List<FrontEndContent> lst = new List<FrontEndContent>();

            lst = db.FrontEndContent.OrderByDescending(m => new { m.NamaPage }).ToList();
            lst = db.FrontEndContent.OrderByDescending(m => new { m.CreatedTime }).ToList();

            return lst;
        }

    }
}
```

but this gives an error :

> 'char' does not contain a definition for 'CreatedTime' and no extension method 'CreatedTime' accepting a first argument of type 'char' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Don't order for string. Order for collections. Use `FrontEndContent dt = db.FrontEndContent.Where(m => m.NamaPage.ToLower() == NamaPage.ToLower()).OrderByDescending(m => m.CreatedTime.ToList()).FirstOfDefault();`

Answer (score 3):

Why are you using the new keyword when you are ordering? You don't need to do that.
This should work just fine.

```
List<FrontEndContent> lst = new List<FrontEndContent>();
        lst = db.FrontEndContent.OrderByDescending(m => m.NamaPage).ToList();
        lst = db.FrontEndContent.OrderByDescending(m => m.CreatedTime).ToList();
        return lst;
```

Answer (score 1):

The error you got can be fixed by not using `new` keyword in the predicate.

```
List<FrontEndContent> lst = new List<FrontEndContent>();
lst = db.FrontEndContent.OrderByDescending(m => m.NamaPage).ToList();
lst = db.FrontEndContent.OrderByDescending(m => m.CreatedTime).ToList();
return lst;
```

But this is still not correct, if you look at the code above, you will only got the `FrontEndContent` which is descendingly ordered by `CreatedTime` because you overwrite the `lst` in the third line.

To order with multiple fields, you need to use `ThenBy` method.

```
List<FrontEndContent> lst = new List<FrontEndContent>();
lst = db.FrontEndContent.OrderByDescending(m => m.NamaPage).ThenByDescending(m => m.CreatedTime).ToList();
return lst;
```

On your `WebService`, you missed a parentesis, and also `ToList` method should be after the sort operation.

```
FrontEndContent dt = db.FrontEndContent.Where(m => m.NamaPage.ToLower() == NamaPage.ToLower()).OrderByDescending(m => m.CreatedTime).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead:

```
FrontEndContent dt = db.FrontEndContent.Where(m => m.NamaPage.ToLower() == NamaPage.ToLower()).OrderByDescending(m => m.CreatedTime).FirstOfDefault();
```

Comment: I think this code won't compile, becouse you call the ToList() method over the CreatedTime property. Perhaps you've ment to call it after the closed bracket. So it's redundant to use ToList(), when you call FirstOrDefault() after that.